Error CANNOT GET / when changing from aws API gateaway v1 to v2
I have this api on NodeJS 20 with express and serverless framework, and I want to change from Api Gateaway v1 to v2 (REST to HTTP), but when I point my api to this v2 gateaway every endpoint is returning CANNOT GET / or status code 400 without any message or logs in cloudwatch, (when in gateaway v1 everything works correctly), in this case I am directing the api for a especific gateaway, but without this I get the same errors

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
